# UML - what does the cross on arrow mean?

Tags: uml

I'm studying some UML materials and I came across one weird thing for me: cross on the side of arrow/association. What does it mean? It's frequently used in the materials, which I am studying. Please see the picture below

[image: crossed UML line]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means non-navigable. Please check page 205 of [UML2.5.1 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF)